# Mapping Class Group of $S^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I am wondering if we can compute $\pi_0(Homeo(S^3))$ (i.e. the group of hoemomorphisms of the three-sphere mod isotopy) or if anyone has a reference where I could find such information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hatcher proved that the group $Homeo(S^3)$ is homotopy equivalent to the orthogonal group. Furthermore, in all dimensions Alexander's trick shows that two homeomorphisms of spheres are isotopic iff they have the same degree (1 or -1).

Comment: So this means that $\pi_0(Homeo(S^3))\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$ correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.